# Importing XML file with special tags & namespaces <abc:xyz> in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, xml

Importing XML file with special tags & namespaces  in mysql. An extract of the xml file I'm using:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<abc:ABCData xmlns:abc="http://www.abc-example.com" xmlns:xyz="http:/www.xyz-example.com">
<abc:ABCHeader>
<abc:ContentDate>2015-08-15T09:03:29.379055+00:00</abc:ContentDate>
<abc:FileContent>PUBLISHED</abc:FileContent>
<abc:RecordCount>310598</abc:RecordCount>
<abc:Extension>
  <xyz:Sources>
    <xyz:Source>
      <xyz:ABC>5967007LIEEXZX4LPK21</xyz:ABC>
      <xyz:Name>Bornheim Register Centre</xyz:Name>
      <xyz:ROCSponsorCountry>NO</xyz:ROCSponsorCountry>
      <xyz:RecordCount>398</xyz:RecordCount>
      <xyz:ContentDate>2015-08-15T05:00:02.952+02:00</xyz:ContentDate>
      <xyz:LastAttemptedDownloadDate>2015-08-15T09:00:01.885686+00:00</xyz:LastAttemptedDownloadDate>
      <xyz:LastSuccessfulDownloadDate>2015-08-15T09:00:02.555222+00:00</xyz:LastSuccessfulDownloadDate>
      <xyz:LastValidDownloadDate>2015-08-15T09:00:02.555222+00:00</xyz:LastValidDownloadDate>
     </xyz:Source>
    </xyz:Sources>
   </abc:Extension>
 </abc:ABCHeader>
<abc:ABCRecords>
 <abc:ABCRecord>
 <abc:ABC>5967007LIEEXZX4LPK21</abc:ABC>
  <abc:Entity>
    <abc:LegalName>REGISTERENHETEN I Bornheim</abc:LegalName>
    <abc:LegalAddress>
      <abc:Line1>Havnegata 48</abc:Line1>
      <abc:City>Bornheim</abc:City>
      <abc:Country>NO</abc:Country>
      <abc:PostalCode>8900</abc:PostalCode>
    </abc:LegalAddress>
    <abc:HeadquartersAddress>
      <abc:Line1>Havnegata 48</abc:Line1>
      <abc:City>Bornheim</abc:City>
      <abc:Country>NO</abc:Country>
      <abc:PostalCode>8900</abc:PostalCode>
    </abc:HeadquartersAddress>
    <abc:BusinessRegisterEntityID register="Enhetsregisteret">974757873</abc:BusinessRegisterEntityID>
    <abc:LegalForm>Organisasjonsledd</abc:LegalForm>
    <abc:EntityStatus>Active</abc:EntityStatus>
  </abc:Entity>
  <abc:Registration>
    <abc:InitialRegistrationDate>2014-06-15T12:03:33.000+02:00</abc:InitialRegistrationDate>
    <abc:LastUpdateDate>2015-06-15T20:45:32.000+02:00</abc:LastUpdateDate>
    <abc:RegistrationStatus>ISSUED</abc:RegistrationStatus>
    <abc:NextRenewalDate>2016-06-15T12:03:33.000+02:00</abc:NextRenewalDate>
    <abc:ManagingLOU>59670054IEEXZX44PK21</abc:ManagingLOU>
  </abc:Registration>
</abc:ABCRecord>
<abc:ABCRecord>
  <abc:ABC>5967007LIE45ZX4MHC90</abc:ABC>
  <abc:Entity>
    <abc:LegalName>SUNNDAL HOSTBANK</abc:LegalName>
    <abc:LegalAddress>
      <abc:Line1>Sunfsalsvegen 15</abc:Line1>
      <abc:City>SUNNDALSPRA</abc:City>
      <abc:Country>NO</abc:Country>
      <abc:PostalCode>6600</abc:PostalCode>
    </abc:LegalAddress>
    <abc:HeadquartersAddress>
      <abc:Line1>Sunndalsvegen 15</abc:Line1>
      <abc:City>SUNNDALSPRA</abc:City>
      <abc:Country>NO</abc:Country>
      <abc:PostalCode>6600</abc:PostalCode>
    </abc:HeadquartersAddress>
    <abc:BusinessRegisterEntityID register="Foretaksregisteret">9373245963</abc:BusinessRegisterEntityID>
    <abc:LegalForm>Hostbank</abc:LegalForm>
    <abc:EntityStatus>Active</abc:EntityStatus>
  </abc:Entity>
  <abc:Registration>
    <abc:InitialRegistrationDate>2014-06-26T15:01:02.000+02:00</abc:InitialRegistrationDate>
    <abc:LastUpdateDate>2015-06-27T15:02:39.000+02:00</abc:LastUpdateDate>
    <abc:RegistrationStatus>ISSUED</abc:RegistrationStatus>
    <abc:NextRenewalDate>2016-06-26T15:01:02.000+02:00</abc:NextRenewalDate>
    <abc:ManagingLOU>5967007LIEEXZX4LPK21</abc:ManagingLOU>
  </abc:Registration>
</abc:ABCRecord>
</abc:ABCRecords>
</abc:ABCData>
```

The below does the job for two records:

```
$dbHost = "localhost";
$dbUser = "root";
$dbPass = "password";
$dbName = "new_xml_extract";

$dbConn = mysqli_connect($dbHost, $dbUser, $dbPass, $dbName);

$delete = $dbConn->query("TRUNCATE TABLE `test_xml`");

$xml = file_get_contents("./xml.xml");

$sxe = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);

$sxe->registerXPathNamespace('a', 'http://www.abc-example.com');

$ABC = $sxe->xpath('//a:ABC');
$LegalName = $sxe->xpath('//a:LegalName');
$RegisterEntityID = $sxe->xpath('//a:BusinessRegisterEntityID');
$LegalForm = $sxe->xpath('//a:LegalForm');
$EntityStatus = $sxe->xpath('//a:EntityStatus');
$InitialRegistrationDate = $sxe->xpath('//a:InitialRegistrationDate');
$LastUpdateDate = $sxe->xpath('//a:LastUpdateDate');
$RegistrationStatus = $sxe->xpath('//a:RegistrationStatus');
$NextRenewalDate = $sxe->xpath('//a:NextRenewalDate');
$ManagingLOU = $sxe->xpath('//a:ManagingLOU');

foreach (array_combine($ABC, $LegalName) as $abc => $legalform) {

$sql = "INSERT INTO `test_xml` (`abc`, `legal_name`)" . "VALUES ('". $dbConn->real_escape_string($abc) ."', '".$dbConn->real_escape_string($legalform)."')";

$result = $dbConn->query($sql);
}
```

That's how all records get inserted into the table:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($ABC); $i++) { 
    $ABC = $ABC[$i]; 
    $LegalName = $LegalName[$i]; 
    $RegisterEntityID = $RegisterEntityID[$i];
    $LegalForm = $LegalForm[$i];
    ....

    // Inserting in mysql (need to be adjusted accordingly)
    ...

    // and/or echoing for testing
    ...
}
```

In some records I got e.g. the letter Ø or Æ. Instead of Ø it reads Ã˜ ... or instead of Æ it reads and writes in the table Ã†.

iconv() http://php.net/manual/de/function.iconv.php does the magic for the foreign characters like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_orthography#Computer_encoding.

So you need to replace e.g. $LegalName with iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1", $LegalName) in your echoing or table insertion! Cheers!

Comment: Could you please explain question 2 a little better?

Comment: Regarding 2 its like ... if I run the script for the first time, I get 7 rows in the mysql table, if I run it for a second time I get 14 rows in the table. 3 times = 21 rows with 3 of each record. So the records are 'adding'. But I want that the table has the same number of original records as in the xml file. At the end I want to update the mysql table each day with a new xml file (which number and entries can vary day by day).

Comment: maybe a SQL error? echo `$result` within the `foreach()`-loop and see what it gets you.

Comment: Thanks Michi. Unfortunately it didn't work though. If I insert "echo $result" within the "foreach()" loop the browser throws back "1111111" but still only 7 entries within the mysql table

Comment: Don't edit your question to make it useless, just delete it instead.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you are looking to reset the entire state of the table, i.e. start from scratch each time, one easy way to do this is to run a "truncate" query on your table before starting the inserts.

See the docs here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/truncate-table.html

Truncating your table will delete all existing data from it, and also reset auto-increment field counters.

Regarding accessing XML attributes with special characters, see the solution here:

[SimpleXML Reading node with a hyphenated name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3626901/simplexml-reading-node-with-a-hyphenated-name)

Comment: Thanks Brendan! The downvote didn't come from me! :-) Truncate helped regarding updating the table. I inserted ... $delete = "TRUNCATE TABLE `test2_xml`"; $truncate = $dbConn->query($delete); ... before the foreach() statement. Do you have any idea why issue 1 (only 7 of 12 rows get inserted) appear?!

Comment: It looks like the four entities that don't get inserted correctly all contain single quotes somewhere in their data. It's likely that they are not being correctly escaped.

You can validate this by echoing the calculated query. It may be worth also trying: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php to see if it helps.

Comment: Hi Brendan! Yes, you are correct. I needed to add real_escape_string() ... like $sql = "INSERT INTO `test2_xml` (`author`, `title`, `genre`, `price`, `publish_date`, `description`)" . "VALUES ('". $dbConn->real_escape_string($author) ."', '".$dbConn->real_escape_string($title)."', '".$dbConn->real_escape_string($genre)."', '".$dbConn->real_escape_string($price)."', '".$dbConn->real_escape_string($publish_date)."', '".$dbConn->real_escape_string($description)."')"; ... I already edited it above. Now I have only the special chararcters in the xml tags left, which I haven't solved yet!

Comment: What issue still remains with special characters?

Comment: Hi Brendan! Please see my edit above. Basically I want to do the same task with this special character xml file

Comment: Have you read over:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3626901/simplexml-reading-node-with-a-hyphenated-name ?

You should be able to do something like:

$xmlL->{'abc:LegalAddress'}

Comment: I did! I can read and print a single tag with the following http://php.net/manual/de/simplexmlelement.registerxpathnamespace.php . Please see above. I'm struggling to bring them together in a loop though.

Comment: Is your goal here to find each ABC, and then for each of those, to get all LegalName elements?

If so, you should be using a nested loop. For each ABC, you should be able to get the child LegalName nodes using something like: $LegalNames = $result->xpath('LegalName') .

See this example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3122166/xpath-query-to-xpath-result-of-query

Comment: The goal is to get each abc tag in the mysql table! I'm able to do it for two records. See above! I want to do it for all of the records though!

Comment: The data you provided only has two ABC tags and two LegalName tags.

The pairs there should be ('5967007LIEEXZX4LPK21', 'REGISTERENHETEN I Bornheim') and ('5967007LIE45ZX4MHC90', 'SUNNDAL HOSTBANK').

It's also worth noting that the data seems to be missing some closing tags, as follows:

</abc:ABCRecords>
</abc:ABCData>

Comment: Thanks for noticing. </abc:ABCRecords> </abc:ABCData> do exist of course. I added them at the sample above. I only posted 2 out of 300,000 records (<abc:ABCRecord>) to show the structure, but I need to have all of the tags in the table. So how can I accomplish this?!

Comment: The above code should do it. If not, make sure to check the count of $ABC and $LegalName.

Comment: Yes, it works fine for two tag contents e.g. in this case $ABC and $LegalName. But how do I get the other ones ($BusinessRegisterEntityID, $LegalForm, $EntityStatus, $InitialRegistrationDate, $LastUpdateDate, $RegistrationStatus, $NextRenewalDate, $ManagingLOU) in as well at the same time?

Comment: One quick and easy way to do it would be to just declare a loop index starting with a value of 0, then iterate, using that index to refer to the element in each array.

Something like:

for ($i = 0; $i < count($ABC); $i++) { $ABCElement = $ABC[$i]; $legalNameElement = $legalName[$i]; $EntityStatusElement = $entityStatus[$i]; ... }

Comment: Perfect! It works great now! One tinny thing, instead of the letter Ø it reads Ã˜ ... or instead of Æ it reads and writes in the table Ã† . What's the issue here and how can I avoid this?!

Comment: It's probably "file_get_contents" doing it. Check out this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236668/file-get-contents-breaks-up-utf-8-characters

Comment: iconv() http://php.net/manual/de/function.iconv.php does the magic for the foreign characters like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_orthography#Computer_encoding.

So I needed to replace e.g. $LegalName with iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1", $LegalName) in the echoing or table insertion! Thanks a lot Brendan for your support here!